# When exactly temporary object in function call is dropped in Rust?

Tags: rust, lifetime

What are scoping rules for temporary objects inside function call in Rust? What I actually interested in whether it is safe to do following:

```
fn foo() -> CString { /* */ }
fn bar(arg: *const libc::c_char) { /* */ }

bar(foo().as_ptr())
```

I created minimal example, and it works as I want -- object is dropped after function call returns.

```
struct Bar {
    pub x: u32
}

impl Bar {
    pub fn new(x: u32) -> Self {
        println!("New Bar made!");
        Bar { x }
    }
    pub fn extract(&self) -> u32{
        self.x
    }
}

impl Drop for Bar {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Bar dropped!");
    }
}

pub fn foo(arg: u32) {
    println!("Function called with arg = {}", arg);
}

fn main () {
    foo(Bar::new(12).extract());
}
```

Can I rely on this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#temporary-lifetimes), under 'Temporary Lifetimes', it says:

> ... the lifetime of temporary values is typically
>
> - the innermost enclosing statement; the tail expression of a block is considered part of the statement that encloses the block, or

The innermost enclosing statement in your case is the call to `bar(  )`. There are examples in the same section very similar to your case.

The compiler would not have compiled your code if this were not the case.

Comment: Note, that `as_ptr()` method is unsafe: it is my responsibility to make sure that pointer is not used after string is dropped, borrow checker does not protect me here.