# Mutex not dropped between function arguments?

Tags: rust

I understand that the following code hangs because the Mutex doesn't get dropped between the arguments (I switched to a RwLock to duck the problem), but ... why not?  I presume this is specified somewhere but I don't seem to be able to hunt it down from the Rust docs.

Thanks.

```rust
use std::sync::{RwLock, Mutex};

pub struct Generic {
    ff: bool,
}

fn test_hang(ff0: bool, ff1: bool) {
    println!("Test: {} {}", ff0, ff1);
}

fn main() {
    let mm = Mutex::new(Generic {ff: true} );
    
    test_hang(mm.lock().unwrap().ff, mm.lock().unwrap().ff);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5775de7bef67fe5ac448329e7c7af22e

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57939935) answer the question? (noting that the guard objects returned by `lock()` are temporary objects in this case).

Comment: Not exactly.  The issue is that two nominally *independent* function arguments have a *linked* lifetime--which seems a bit odd.  Note: this *also* applies to println!(), for example, so it's not just functional calls that exhibit this.

Comment: @AndrewLentvorski It is the same. Temporaries are (usually) dropped at the innermost statement, and there are two temporaries here, both dropped _after_ the call.

Comment: But a function argument isn't an expression, either.  You can't chain "fn main() { 1, 2, 3 }" in Rust, for example.

Comment: Function argument is definitely an expression, but comma isn't a thing.

Comment: You have two active and open expressions with their own lifetimes.  That occurs nowhere else in Rust.

Comment: I'm don't really understand your point. Exactly the same thing happens if you do this: `let xx: (bool,bool) = (mm.lock().unwrap().ff, mm.lock().unwrap().ff);`.

Comment: @AndrewLentvorski It does, for example [with arrays](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=07cb4b40bc160a81e955e19fa56dc2ea).

Comment: Instead of using a `RwLock`, you can also avoid the issue using blocks: `test_hang({let ff = mm.lock().unwrap().ff; ff}, {let ff = mm.lock().unwrap().ff; ff})` ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a8f18a5cb25720c3e290fd39a84391bc)).